# how to set the button so as not to force close when empty EditText

Tags: android, button

had a problem about the intent button if EditText blank it will force close how to cope when EditText edit text1 and 2 empty and no force

MyActivity.java

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Hitung Luas Persegi Panjang");

        edtPanjang = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_panjang);
        edtLebar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_lebar);
        btnHitung = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_hitung);
        txtLuas = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_luas);

    btnHitung.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String panjang = edtPanjang.getText().toString().trim();
            String lebar = edtLebar.getText().toString().trim();

            double p = Double.parseDouble(panjang);
            double l = Double.parseDouble(lebar);

            double luas = p * l;


            txtLuas.setText("Luas : " + luas);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What are value in panjang and lebar?

Comment: You should do as below. Put it inside a try catch block                                       




   double p = new Double(panjang.getText().toString());
   double l = new Double(lebar.getText().toString());